# Bounding the difference between moments of random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables whose distributions are close in some sense. I am interested in bounding the diffrence between the $k$th moments of $X$ and $Y$ (under certain conditions). A few possible approaches I can think of are:

1. Bounding the Wasserstein distance between $X$ and $Y$ and then use its equivalent definition to bound $
   |\mathbb{E}f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(Y)|$ for all 1-Lipschitz functions $f$. The Problem is that power functions are not 1-Lipschitz.
2. Bounding the generating funcitons of $X$ and $Y$ and go from there.
3. Directly using definition.

I think this problem must have been considered. So to avoid reinventing the wheel, I'll really appreciate if you could point me to the right directions and references (ideally, I also want to bound $
|\mathbb{E}f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(Y)|$ for more complicated functions $f$ than just power functions). Thanks!

Comment: Minor comment: For any $k>0$ we have $$E[|X|^k] = \int_0^{\infty}P[|X|^k>t]dt = \int_0^{\infty} P[|X|>t^{1/k}]dt$$  So if $P[|X|>t] \leq \beta P[|Y|>t]$ for all $t\geq 0$ (for some $\beta >0$) then $E[|X|^k] \leq \beta E[|Y|^k]$.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for your comment. I alluded this in the third approach, namely $\mathbb{E} X^k = \int_0^\infty t^k\mathbb{P}(X>t)dt$. Also, this question can be reformulated as when does convergence in $L_1$ imply convergence in $L_p$ - now I suspect there must be a known result, just not sure if a more specific bound than just asymptotic convergence is available.

Comment: The definition in your above comment is not correct. (at Legon)

Comment: Ah right, should be $kt^{k-1}$ and for nonnegative random variables.

Comment: Yes, $$X\geq 0 \implies \frac{X^{k+1}}{k+1} = \int_0^{\infty} t^k 1_{\{X>t\}} dt$$ so $\frac{E[X^{k+1}]}{k+1}$ is the integral you wrote.